# Why doesn't this query work and this one does?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL Shell, two nearly identical queries. One works, one doesn't. The difference is a key word. Why is that?

The working query just gets a salary of your choice depending on what limit number you use in the subquery. So "Limit 4" would give you the fourth highest salary.

```
SELECT SALARY
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT SALARY
      FROM TBLEMPLOYEE
      ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 3
      ) RESULT
ORDER BY SALARY LIMIT 1
```

This successfully gives the third highest salary.

If I remove the word "result" it no longer works. What function does result serve? Is that an alias? I get this:
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Because table aliases are required for derived tables in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, it's an alias. (In the SQL standard, it's called a "correlation name".) MySQL requires a correlation name for the inline view. In the MySQL parlance, the inline view (the SELECT in parens following the FROM keyword) is called a "derived table". And MySQL requires a name to be assigned The name has to follow the rules for valid identifiers. It doesn't specifically need to be `result`, we could use `r2d2` or `v`.

Answer (score 1):

Every derived table (AKA sub-query) must indeed have an alias. I.e. each query in brackets must be given an alias (AS whatever), which can the be used to refer to it in the rest of the outer query.Yes result is an alias.it could be any name in the place of result like myalias or something else.

```
SELECT SALARY
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT SALARY
      FROM TBLEMPLOYEE
      ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 3
      ) AS RESULT
ORDER BY SALARY LIMIT 1
```

more example

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID,
             msisdn 
      FROM (SELECT * FROM TT2) as myalias
     ) as anotheralias;
```